# Prevent return key expect on textarea field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5.1

I have a form where I used the following code to prevent the return key, which works as expected.

#### view laravel (blade template)

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'orders.store', 'onkeypress' => 'return event.keyCode != 13;']) !!}
```

#### compiles to html

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://foo.bar.com/en/orders" 
accept-charset="UTF-8" 
onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
```

Now I have the circumstance, that I need the return key available in my textarea field. Expect this textarea field the behavious should be as before (prevent return key)

I tried to accomplish that, but struggle. Heres my last not working result:

#### view laravel (blade template)

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'orders.store', 'onkeypress' => 'return (( event.keyCode != 13 ) && $("note").is( ":focus") );']) !!}
// ...
{!! Form::textarea('note', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'wrap' => 'physical']) !!}
```

#### compiles to html

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://foo.bar.com/en/orders" 
accept-charset="UTF-8" 
onkeypress="return (( event.keyCode != 13 ) &amp;&amp; $(&quot;note&quot;).is( &quot;:focus&quot;) );">
<!-- ... -->
<textarea class="form-control" wrap="physical" name="note" cols="50" rows="10" id="note"></textarea>
```

Any hints how I can get the return key in the textarea, but still avoid the return key in the input fields?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the keypress event from bubbling from the textarea to the form. I'm not familiar with laravel but this is the onkeypress you need added to the textarea html

```
onkeypress="event.stopPropagation();"
```